# Justifying objects correctly within wrappanel when objects resize

Tags: c#, wpf, stackpanel, wrappanel

It's difficult to describe my problem in a few words!
This is what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

Object #1 normally fills up the width of its parent.
It can be minimised to a fraction of its former width, and when that happens, it is *right-aligned* in its parent. Object #2 should automatically slide up to fill the gap, and is *left-aligned*..

I have tried various stackpanels, wrappanels, and dockpanels - but can't figure out the layout issue.

Is there a method to allow this behaviour without lots of ugly maths in code-behind?

Comment: resize #1, and reorder the two inside the `WrapPanel`. Need to do some math in calculating the new size, of course.

Comment: @kennyzx, you *may* have misunderstood the problem... I don't think that the `WrapPanel` will swap the order of the two elements when the first one is minimised... do you?

Comment: #1 should be right-aligned, and #2 should be left-aligned. That is my main problem.

Comment: Setting the `HorizontalAlignment` property here won't help you. Perhaps you could swap the actual positions of the items when the object is minimised by [writing a custom `Panel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152(v=vs.110).aspx#Panels_custom_panel_elements)? Alternatively, you might be able to create a `UserControl` that pairs the two objects and adjusts them at the appropriate moment for you... then add the `UserControl`s to the `WrapPanel` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I came up with something. Perhaps not the most elegant in the world - but it works for my use-case.

```
public class CollapsingPanel : Panel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// parents are supposed to ask their children what their desired size is, given an available size
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="availableSize"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        var availableSizeOnThisLine = new Rect(new Point(0, 0), new Size(availableSize.Width, 0));
        var panelDesiredSize = new Size(availableSize.Width, 0);

        foreach (FrameworkElement child in InternalChildren)
        {
            child.Measure(availableSize);
            var childSize = child.DesiredSize;

            if (childSize.Width > availableSizeOnThisLine.Size.Width)
            {
                // this child will overflow this line: New line!
                panelDesiredSize.Height += availableSizeOnThisLine.Height;
                availableSizeOnThisLine = new Rect(new Point(0, panelDesiredSize.Height), new Size(availableSize.Width, childSize.Height));

                availableSizeOnThisLine.Width -= childSize.Width; // subtract this area/width
                availableSizeOnThisLine.Height = childSize.Height;
            }
            else
            {
                // this child will fit on this line..
                var thisChildRectangle = new Rect(childSize);
                if (child.HorizontalAlignment == HorizontalAlignment.Left)
                {
                    thisChildRectangle.Location = new Point(availableSizeOnThisLine.Left, availableSizeOnThisLine.Top);
                    availableSizeOnThisLine.Location.Offset(childSize.Width, 0); // move to the right
                } 
                else if (child.HorizontalAlignment == HorizontalAlignment.Right)
                {
                    thisChildRectangle.Location = new Point(availableSizeOnThisLine.Right - childSize.Width, availableSizeOnThisLine.Top);
                }

                child.Arrange(thisChildRectangle);
                availableSizeOnThisLine.Width -= childSize.Width; // subtract child's width from avbailable space
                availableSizeOnThisLine.Height = Math.Max(availableSizeOnThisLine.Height, childSize.Height);

                panelDesiredSize.Height = Math.Max(childSize.Height, panelDesiredSize.Height);
            }
        }

        return panelDesiredSize;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// parents position their children and tell their children how much size they are actually getting
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="finalSize"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        var availableSizeOnThisLine = new Rect(new Point(0, 0), new Size(finalSize.Width, 0));

        foreach (FrameworkElement child in InternalChildren)
        {
            var childSize = child.DesiredSize;

            if (childSize.Width > availableSizeOnThisLine.Size.Width) 
            {
                // going to wrap around
                var thisChildRectangle = new Rect(child.DesiredSize);
                availableSizeOnThisLine = new Rect(new Point(0, availableSizeOnThisLine.Height), new Size(finalSize.Width, childSize.Height));

                if (child.HorizontalAlignment == HorizontalAlignment.Right)
                {
                    thisChildRectangle.Location = new Point(availableSizeOnThisLine.Right - thisChildRectangle.Width, availableSizeOnThisLine.Top);
                }
                else if (child.HorizontalAlignment == HorizontalAlignment.Left)
                {
                    thisChildRectangle.Location = new Point(availableSizeOnThisLine.Left, availableSizeOnThisLine.Top);
                }

                child.Arrange(thisChildRectangle);
            }
            else
            {
                // put on this line
                var thisChildRectangle = new Rect(child.DesiredSize);
                if (child.HorizontalAlignment == HorizontalAlignment.Right)
                {
                    thisChildRectangle.Location = new Point(availableSizeOnThisLine.Right - thisChildRectangle.Width, availableSizeOnThisLine.Top);
                }
                else if (child.HorizontalAlignment == HorizontalAlignment.Left)
                {
                    thisChildRectangle.Location = new Point(availableSizeOnThisLine.Left, availableSizeOnThisLine.Top);
                }

                child.Arrange(thisChildRectangle);
                availableSizeOnThisLine.Width -= thisChildRectangle.Width; // subtract child's width from avbailable space
            }
            availableSizeOnThisLine.Height = Math.Max(childSize.Height, availableSizeOnThisLine.Height);
        }

        return finalSize;
    }
```